# Permissions для приложения в Facebook

Tags: facebook, permissions

Проблема следующая: имеется приложение в Фейсбуке (создано для внешнего сайта), в приложении разрешены доступы к emails, public_profile, user_friends и одобрено Фейсбуком использование user_work_history.

Однако при авторизации на внешнем сайте через Фейсбук в окошке авторизации нет возможности выбрать права на emails, user_friends и user_work_history.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: 0) делал только игры, но для сайтов должно быть то же самое 1) это для нового пользователя или для всех? При смене разрешений для старых пользователей надо `auth_type=rerequest` передавать 2) вы бы код привели, там же самому надо разрешения передавать

Comment: для всех пользователей (пробовал у себя, удалял на своей странице facebook доступ для приложения полностью, и заново авторизовался на внешнем сайте)

Comment: когда удалили приложение - вы становитесь новым пользователем. Имелось ввиду другое: я залогинился в приложение, потом вы решили добавить в запрашиваемые разрешения email. У меня это разрешение запрошено не будет (т.к. я старый пользователь) до тех пор, пока `auth_type=rerequest` не передадите в окно логина. И без кода трудно что-то сказать: вы может просто забыли эти разрешения запросить (public_profile запрашивается автоматически без вашего участия)

Comment: Да, вы правы, передаю только AppId и AppSecret. Оказывается права  надо передавать в Scope=/